# Remove 2 or more blank spaces from a string in c#..?

Tags: c#

what is the efficient mechanism to remove 2 or more white spaces from a string leaving single white space.

I mean if string is "a____b" the output must be "a_b".

Comment: Are you asking, if someone accidentally double spaces how can you correct all instances of that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace multiple spaces:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, " {2,}", " ");
```

Comment: @Nick: Yes. The quantifier `{2,}` makes the expression match two or more spaces.

Comment: what do the literals actually imply, I mean in {2,} what does the 2 represent and why there is nothing after the comma. Just getting a complete view on solution.

Comment: @Gunner = `{2,}` means two or more. Leaving out the upper limit, it can be any number. `{2,5}` would have meant between 2 and 5 inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Something like below maybe:

```
var b=a.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var noMultipleSpaces = string.Join(" ",b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string tempo = "this    is    a     string    with    spaces";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", options);     
tempo = regex.Replace(tempo, @" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can user this method n pass your string value as argument 
you have to add one namespace also using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string RemoveMultipleWhiteSpace(string str)

```
{



    // A.
    // Create the Regex.
    Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");

    // B.
    // Remove multiple spaces.
    string s3 = r.Replace(str, @" ");
    return s3;

}
```